# Quantmod: Calculate Gap of yesterday and choose the stock by user prompt

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to calculate the GAP of a Stock using quantmod library and a user input to select the stock.

First I get the user to input the stock, i.e. "NKE" 
Then I use getSymbols to create a dataframe NKE

```
S1 <- readline("Enter a symbol please: ")
S2 <- getSymbols(S1,from="2018-01-01", auto.assign=TRUE)
```

Now I work in the NKE dataframe to create new column called NKE.GAP

```
NKE.GAP=vector(mode="numeric",length = nrow(NKE$NKE.Open))
```

Now I'd like to  calculate the GAP but don't know how to select automatically yesterday's NKE.Open value and NKE.Close of 2 days ago.

```
NKE$"NKE.GAP"=NKE$NKE.Open-NKE$NKE.Close
```

[NKE Stock example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHONJ.jpg)

My two problems here are 2:

-How to select cells of different dates to calculate the GAP?

-How to automate the process like if instead of NKE (NIKE) , I'd like to calculate GAP for other stock i.e. UAA (Under Armour) by using a readline (user input)

Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Thanks Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define input parameters first:

```
library(quantmod)

S1 <- readline("Enter a symbol please: ")
gapLag <- 2 #  select cells of different dates
```

A new data frame with a generic name needs to be created first. It allows working with different tickers:

```
finData <- getSymbols(S1,from="2018-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)
finData$GAP1 <- finData[ ,1] - finData[ ,4] # positions of Open and Close columns don't change
```

The last column contains GAP of period specified in variable `gapLag`

```
finData$GAPuser <- finData[ ,1] - lag(finData[,4], gapLag)
```

**EDIT:** Create a new data frame named after the ticker:

```
assign(S1, finData)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One final question: is there any way to get the new dataframe name to be the name of the Stock instead of "finData", something like "Rename finData to S1 Value" to get "NKE" instead of "finData" as a name? This will prevent to overwrite all the time finData data frame.  Any idea about how to get this? Again thanks.